# Knockout: Mapping with multiple keys

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Is it possible to use the ko.mapping Plugin to check for multiple keys? Something like this...

```
var mapping = {
     key: function(data) {
         return ko.unwrap(data.id) && ko.unwrap(data.name)
     }
}
```

I want the Mapping Plugin to only add new items to the observableArray when the combination of `id` and `name` is not already used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe so.  Just concatenate them both into a string and return it.

```
var mapping = {
     key: function(data) {
         return ko.unwrap(data.id) + '_' + ko.unwrap(data.name);
     }
}
```

The underscore delimiter (or pipe or whatever you choose to use) should help with any key collisions like one object with id='12' name='times' and another with id='1' and name='2times'.